# Simple differential equation $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{y'}{x+1}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{y'}{x+1}$$

The solution to this is very easy, we just multiply both sides by 
$$(x+1)y\ \mathrm dx$$
Then we have

$$(x^2+x)\ \mathrm dx=y\ \mathrm dy$$
Then we integrate both sides to get solution

$$\frac{x^3}{3}+ \frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{y^2}{2} + C, C\in \mathbb{R}$$

But I don't understand how can we divide by $y$ and $x+1$. What if $y=0$ or $x=-1$? What happens then?

Comment: From the form of the DE given at the start it is implied that $x=-1$ and $y=0$ are excluded from the domain and range respectively. It would be worth checking/including that at the end.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{1}{x+1}\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$$
The above equation does not hold for $x=-1$ and $y=0$ because division by zero is undefined. This implies that $-1$ is excluded from the domain of $y$ and $0$ is excluded from the codomain of $y$. Therefore we can safely divide by $x+1$ and $y$, respectively. We can also proceed as follows
$$x^2+x=y\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$$
$$\int x^2+x\ \mathrm dx=\int y\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\ \mathrm dx$$
$$\int x^2\ \mathrm dx+\int x\ \mathrm dx=\int y\ \mathrm dy$$
$$\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^2}{2}+C=\frac{y^2}{2}$$
$$y^2=\frac{2x^3}{3}+x^2+C$$
$$\left|y\right|=\sqrt{\frac{2x^3}{3}+x^2+C}$$
Therefore the solutions are
$$y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2x^3}{3}+x^2+C}$$
Where $-1$ is excluded from the domain of $y$ and $0$ is excluded from the codomain of $y$.

Comment: +1 I think the $\int...\frac {dy}{dx}\;dx $ step is important.

Answer (score 1):

From the form of the DE given at the start it is implied that $x=−1$ and $y=0$ are excluded from the domain and range respectively. If you had an an initial condition this has more impact on your question.

Suppose you had the initial condition that $y\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=\frac{3}{2}$. This initial condition will result in $c=0$.

So the solution to the DE is $\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{y^2}{2}$. We must exclude $x=-1$ and $y=0$ from possible solutions.

When $x=-1$ then $\frac{-1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{y^2}{2}\implies y=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

When $y=0$ then $\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^2}{2}=0\implies x=0,x=-\frac{3}{2}$.

So these values would need to be excluded from your domain/range.

Comment: Why the fact that when $x=-1$ then $y=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and when $y=0$ then $x=-\frac{3}{2}$ means that we have to exclude these two values from domain. What would happen if i had equation $\frac{dy}{dx}x(1-y)=y$ for example, what would then happen if $y=0$ and what if $x=0$? This doesn't seem completely clear to me.

Comment: Those numerical values related to the example I gave including an initial condition. Your problem didn't have one. They were added to highlight how the exclusion of certain values could be handled. In the initial DE it does not make sense if $x=-1$ or if $y=0$ so these values are not allowed. In the version in your comment with no division there are no restrictions required.

Comment: Well, when i try to solve this i have to divide both sides by $xy$ and multiply them by $dx$. Now, what happens then, i mean i will have to exclude $x=0$ and $y=0$ from the solution in order to proceed with the solving, but what's going on when $x=0$ and $y=0$.

Comment: You should consider those as separate cases. A valid solution to the DE in your comment is $y=0$. And your solution would include a $\ln|x|$ term which would imply that $x=0$ is excluded.

Comment: How can i know that $y=0$ is solution to that DE, and solution includes $ln|y|$ term too, what about that?

Comment: Before you divide by $y$ you need to consider the two cases, either $y=0$ or $y\neq0$. If we look at the $y=0$ case it is a valid solution as $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of $y=0$ is zero so satisfies the DE. Then you would look at the $y\neq0$ case as a separate case and when it gets to $\ln|y|$ you are already covered as you are looking at the $y\neq0$ case.